# Why shift operator is not homotopic to 1 ($K_1$-approach)?

Tags: operator-algebras, fake-proofs, k-theory

Let us recall that via fourier transform it holds true that $C^*(S)\cong C(\mathbb{T})$, with map given by $S\mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$ (considering $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). It is also true that $K_1(C(\mathbb{T}))=\mathbb{Z}[e^{2\pi i x}]$, so it follows that
$$K_1(C^*(S))=\mathbb{Z}[S],$$
and of coure this implies that $S$ is not homotopic to the identity (if it were, $[S]=[1]$ and then $K_0(C^*(S))$ would be the trivial group).

On the other side, let us define $u(t)=e^{2\pi i x t}$ and observe that

- $u(0)=1$ and $u(1)=e^{2\pi i x}$
- $u(t)$ is norm continuous since 
  \begin{equation}
  \begin{array}{rl}
  ||u(t)-u(s)||&=||e^{2\pi i x t}(1-e^{2\pi i x (s-t)})||\\
               &\leq||1-\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(2\pi i x (s-t))^k}{k!}||\\
               &=||\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(2\pi i x (s-t))^k}{k!}||\\
               &\leq||(2\pi i x (s-t))\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(2\pi i x (s-t))^k}{(k+1)!}||\\
              &\leq||(2\pi i x (s-t))||\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{||(2\pi i x (s-t))^k||}{(k+1)!}\\
              &\leq|s-t|\sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{(2\pi)^k}{k!} = e^{2\pi}|t-s|
  \end{array}
  \end{equation}
- $u(t)$ is unitary for every $t$, since $u(t)^*=e^{-2\pi i x t}$ and then $u(t)u(t)^*=1$.
- $u(t)\in C(\mathbb{T})$ by functional calculus, since $u(t)$ is a continuous function of $e^{2\pi i x}$ for every $t\in[0,1]$.

This proves that $e^{2\pi i x}$ is homotopic to $1$ and of course that the shift operator $S$ is homotopic to the identity, which **can't** be true, so... where is the issue?

Comment: Do you mean $K_1$ throughout?  $K_0$ is generated by projections, yet I see not one projection in this post.

Comment: Edited! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you've found is a path connecting $S$ and $1$ in the unitary group of $\mathbb B(\ell^2(\mathbb Z))$.  What you've failed to show is that for all $t\in[0,1]$, $u(t)\in C^*(S)$, i.e., you haven't shown that $S$ and $1$ are homotopic in $C^*(S)$.  But this is a good thing, because it's not true, and one way to see this is through $K$-theory:  the class of $S$ in $K_1(C^*(S))\cong\mathbb Z$ is a generator, while the class of $1$ is the identity.

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any idea why my path is not contained in $C^*(S)$ though? That is, what is wrong with the functional calculus argument?

Comment: While $u_t\in L^\infty(\mathbb T)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$, it is not continuous:  viewing $\mathbb T$ as $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$, we have $u_t(0)=1$ and $u_t(1)=e^{2\pi it}\neq1$ unless $t=0$ or $1$.